# Actual usage of "perfect continues" tense

Tags: verbs

**Perfect** tense is about the completion of an action.

**Continuous** tense is about ongoing action.

What is the usage for **Perfect Continuous** tense?

For example, **I have been walking**. It's completed, and it still ongoing. I got confused.

> Summary:
>
> Perfect Tense vs. Completion
>
> Continuous vs. Ongoing
>
> Perfect Continuous vs ????????????

Comment: These are not "tenses". Please take such "questions" to our sister site.

Answer (score 3):

It is simply not true that "Perfect tense is about the completion of an action".

The present perfect construction is used for events or activities which have present relevance. The precise meaning of that relevance is variable: often it means the event was recent; or sometimes that its effects are still current. Sometimes (especially when combined with the "continuous") it can be that the event is still in progress.

Note that the use of aspectual markers like "perfect" and "continuous" is often a choice that the speaker can make depending on how they wish to present the events, rather than a choice forced by the objective facts.

So in some circumstances *I walked*, *I have walked* and *I have been walking* are all possible ways of referring to the same situation (when I have recently finished walking).

In another set of circumstances *I am walking* and *I have been walking* are possible ways of referring to the same situation (when my walking started a while ago, and is still continuing).

Comment: Under what scenario to use which phrase is more accurate?

Comment: (Sitting down for lunch) - "I'm really hungry - I've walked six miles this morning" or "I've been walking all morning".  On the road - "I'm walking to Newtown. I've been walking for two hours and I'm still nowhere near it."

Comment: @user1187968, my point about the speaker's choice was meant to explain that none of the options is more or less accurate than the others: they are different choices about how the speaker wishes to relate themselves, the hearers, and other events in the narrative, to the events described.